# Union all 2 queries while ordering each query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I union all 2 queries but also have each query sorted before I union all them?
I am looking to get the top 20 results for EACH year after the results are ordered by sum([docextprice]) desc

Here is an example of what I have now:

```
SELECT      top 20 gm.[partnum]
            ,p.PartDescription
            ,sum([docextprice])[docextprice]
            ,year([invoicedate])year
            ,'Eco Surfaces' product

FROM        dbo.gm gm
            JOIN dbo.Part p on gm.partnum = p.PartNum

WHERE       gm.company = 'EII' and [invoicedate] BETWEEN  '20100809' and '20101231'
            and p.ClassID in ('mpe') 


GROUP BY    year([invoicedate]),gm.[partnum],p.PartDescription
ORDER BY    year([invoicedate]),sum([docextprice]) desc

UNION ALL

SELECT      top 20 gm.[partnum]
            ,p.PartDescription
            --,gm.[prodcode]
            --,p.ClassID
            ,sum([docextprice])[docextprice]
            ,year([invoicedate])year
            ,'Eco Surfaces' product

FROM        dbo.gm gm
            JOIN dbo.Part p on gm.partnum = p.PartNum

WHERE       gm.company = 'EII' and [invoicedate] BETWEEN  '20110101' and '20111231'
            and p.ClassID in ('mpe') 


GROUP BY    year([invoicedate]),gm.[partnum],p.PartDescription
ORDER BY    year([invoicedate]),sum([docextprice]) desc
```

Obviously, this query won't won't because you can't order by on both sides of the join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using common table expressions to hold the results before you union them together:

```
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT TOP 20
                        gm.[partnum] ,
                        p.PartDescription ,
                        SUM([docextprice]) [docextprice] ,
                        YEAR([invoicedate]) year ,
                        'Eco Surfaces' product
               FROM     dbo.gm gm
                        JOIN dbo.Part p ON gm.partnum = p.PartNum
               WHERE    gm.company = 'EII'
                        AND [invoicedate] BETWEEN '20100809' AND '20101231'
                        AND p.ClassID IN ( 'mpe' )
               GROUP BY YEAR([invoicedate]) ,
                        gm.[partnum] ,
                        p.PartDescription
               ORDER BY YEAR([invoicedate]) ,
                        SUM([docextprice]) DESC
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT TOP 20
                        gm.[partnum] ,
                        p.PartDescription
                        --,gm.[prodcode]
                        --,p.ClassID
                        ,
                        SUM([docextprice]) [docextprice] ,
                        YEAR([invoicedate]) year ,
                        'Eco Surfaces' product
               FROM     dbo.gm gm
                        JOIN dbo.Part p ON gm.partnum = p.PartNum
               WHERE    gm.company = 'EII'
                        AND [invoicedate] BETWEEN '20110101' AND '20111231'
                        AND p.ClassID IN ( 'mpe' )
               GROUP BY YEAR([invoicedate]) ,
                        gm.[partnum] ,
                        p.PartDescription
               ORDER BY YEAR([invoicedate]) ,
                        SUM([docextprice]) DESC
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a `UNION`:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT      gm.[partnum]
                ,p.PartDescription
                ,sum([docextprice])[docextprice]
                ,year([invoicedate]) [year]
                ,'Eco Surfaces' product

    FROM        dbo.gm gm
                JOIN dbo.Part p on gm.partnum = p.PartNum

    WHERE       gm.company = 'EII' 
    and [invoicedate] BETWEEN  '20100809' and '20111231'
                and p.ClassID in ('mpe') 
    GROUP BY    year([invoicedate]),gm.[partnum],p.PartDescription
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [year] ORDER BY [docextprice] DESC)
    FROM CTE1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
WHERE RN <= 20
```

Comment: I don't think this would give you the desired results if you had 5 results from the first time period and 35 from the second, instead of the top 20 from the first time period and the top 20 from the second time period.  Right?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Why not?, if the first time period has only 5 rows as a result, then `RN` for that year will go till 5, and if the second year go to 35 rows, then `RN` will go to 35 for that year. So `RN <= 20` works just fine for the desired results

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that well.  It looks like the OP wants 40 total results, 20 from one time period (20100809 thru 20101231) and 20 from another time period (20110101 thru 20111231).  Couldn't your solution return the top 5 from the first time period and the top 35 from the second time period, if the data occurs like that?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg No, my answer wouldn't work like that, because the `ROW_NUMBER` is being partitioned by `YEAR`, so it **will** return 20 rows from each year if there are that many results for that year

Comment: Ok, so that should work as long as the two time periods are cutoff at the end of a year, right?  If the first time period went to 20110131 and the next picked up at 20110201, you'd have problems.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Yes, of course. It works in this case and wouldn't work in the situation you explained. This answer is following the "I want the top 20 results for EACH year after the results are ordered by sum([docextprice]) desc" requirement from op

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just remove order by in the first query from you original script. You can only have one order by statement in a batch.

```
SELECT      top 20 gm.[partnum]
            ,p.PartDescription
            ,sum([docextprice])[docextprice]
            ,year([invoicedate])year
            ,'Eco Surfaces' product

FROM        dbo.gm gm
            JOIN dbo.Part p on gm.partnum = p.PartNum

WHERE       gm.company = 'EII' and [invoicedate] BETWEEN  '20100809' and '20101231'
            and p.ClassID in ('mpe') 


GROUP BY    year([invoicedate]),gm.[partnum],p.PartDescription


UNION ALL

SELECT      top 20 gm.[partnum]
            ,p.PartDescription
            --,gm.[prodcode]
            --,p.ClassID
            ,sum([docextprice])[docextprice]
            ,year([invoicedate])year
            ,'Eco Surfaces' product

FROM        dbo.gm gm
            JOIN dbo.Part p on gm.partnum = p.PartNum

WHERE       gm.company = 'EII' and [invoicedate] BETWEEN  '20110101' and '20111231'
            and p.ClassID in ('mpe') 


GROUP BY    year([invoicedate]),gm.[partnum],p.PartDescription
ORDER BY    year([invoicedate]),sum([docextprice]) desc
```